# How to design a menu Bar like ckEditor

Tags: javascript, css, ckeditor, menubar

I am trying to design a Menu bar like [`ckeditor`](http://ckeditor.com/demo) or [`TinyMCE`](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php). Any idea how to design as i have just sufficient knowledge about `CSS and JS` so i can do that my own but not getting any clue after spending so much time on ckEditor using firebug console.

[image]

Comment: if you go throgh ckEditor using firebug console, you can not get any point very easily about the `menu bar`, this is what i have asked

Comment: This is not really a question - it's much, much too broad. Which aspect of doing it do you have a problem with?

Comment: As Pekka said, can you be more specific about what part of the design you're having trouble with? There's a lot going on in that screenshot; icons, backgrounds, dropdown lists (and probably hover and mousedown effects too)

Comment: @RichardEv, as i have attached one image which is the `menubar` of ckEditor and i wanted to design the same menu bar but it's too complex to understand the CSS for me so i thought to ask if anybody knows about that.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look at normal navigation menu methods - ie create a list with links - you can style the list with images or drop down menus as you wish ... check List Apart for horizontally styling lists -> http://www.alistapart.com/articles/horizdropdowns

Comment: Thanks ManseUK, i designed the a normal navigation menu but ckeditor's menu is much pretier than me. but getting no clue how do they designed actually. anyway thanks

Comment: @user575363 for styling of the images i suggest the other answer from bibhaw is the way to go

Comment: Thanks ManseUK, given link by you helped me a lot to understand the Menu design. Many thanks...